# Changing from SHA-1 to SHA-512

Tags: java, security, sha

I am trying to change from SHA-1 to SHA-512 to have a better security but I am not totally clear how I can do the change.

This is my method with SHA-1:

```
public static String sha1Convert(String password) {
            try {
                MessageDigest crypt = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
                crypt.reset();
                crypt.update(password.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                return byteToHex(crypt.digest());
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(UserLoginManaged.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

This is the method I have been doing but I am not sure if its working totally good because (and I am sorry if I am doing something wrong). I am changing the sha-1 to the sha-512, but then when I try to log on to my applications it tells me that the password is wrong. So I am not sure if it is that I hace the method wrong or if I am just ignorant about something.

```
public static String sha512Convert(String password) {
    try {
        MessageDigest sh = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
        sh.reset();
        sh.update(password.getBytes());
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte b : sh.digest()) sb.append(Integer.toHexString(0xff & b));
        return sb.toString();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Logger.getLogger(UserLoginManaged.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is little difference between SHA-1 and SHA-512 from a password security viewpoint, both can be computed in under 1us. There are reasons to upgrade from SHA-1 but this isn't one.

Don't use a hash for password protection, use functions such as PBKDF2 (aka Rfc2898DeriveBytes), password_hash/password_verify, Bcrypt and similar functions.

Passwords are "cracked" these days by trying passwords from a 10 million word list. The time to hash a password is < 1us on a laptop, and attacker will be orders of magnitude faster. Unless it is spearfishing an attacker will be happy with the easiest 90%.

The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Protecting your users is important, please use secure password methods.

Comment: Having better security is not the only reason I want to change to SHA-512. But it was a just one of them. Still thanks for the comment